# What is the usage of assigning "this" object to a variable inside a function?

Tags: javascript

I've seen things like this:

```
function fnx(){
 ctrl = this;
 this.thisedVar = "thisedVar from fnx"
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what is it useful for. if that function is executed and then this is compared to ctrl, they are the same:

```
fnx();
console.log(this === ctrl) // true
```

That's why I don't understand what is the purpose of assigning `this` to a variable.

Can anyone explain it, please? Thanks.

Comment: So that the *this* you want is accessible from another scope. E.g. inside of a callback

Comment: Could you please provide a small example? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Have a look at where `ctrl` is declared and in what other locations it is used. If you don't show us the complete code, we can't tell you what it is used for.

Comment: If you declared another function inside of `function fnx() { ... }`, and inside that nested function wanted to refer to `fnx`, you could not. By storing a reference to `fnx` as a variable, you can now access it from anywhere within.

Comment: Why would you set a variable to another variable. To hold a reference to the value/object. Same thing here. Something needed a reference to this at that moment in time, hard to know what it is since you id not show all the code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = function() {

 var THIS = this;
 this.s = "Hello World";
 this.runMe = function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
   console.log(this.s);
  }, 100);
 }
 
}

var a2 = function() {

 var THIS = this;
 this.s = "Hello World";
 this.runMe = function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
   console.log(THIS.s);
  }, 100);
 }
 
}

b = new(a);
b.runMe();

b2 = new(a2);
b2.runMe()
```

Outputs:

undefined

Hello World

Class a (object b) returns undefined because that `this` is in the scope of the callback.

Class a2 (object b2) returns `Hello World` because that `this` belongs to the class a2.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a variable to a value without using `var` it refers to global variable. So if you are assigning `this` to `ctrl` it means the your are assigning Window obecjt `this` to a global variable `ctrl.

So when you compare `ctrl` with `this` (again Window) object, it is same since you are matching after function execution.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the value of **this** is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding). It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called.

You assign THIS to a variable so you save this value.

Read more: https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/javascript-this-4-rules-7354abdb274c